# Under the circumstances (holiday, overworked SE employees), when can I expect my profile to be deleted for SE Meta?

Tags: support, profile-page, deleted-accounts

I requested deletion of my profile on SE Meta on 12/23/19.  My profile states

> This account is scheduled to be deleted Dec 24 at 14:38.

That is 96 hours ago.  I realize that this is a holiday week and many employees are probably taking days off, but I am asking when can I expect my profile to be deleted? I am concerned that my request fell through a crack.

Comment: High rep accounts go through the manual queue, that takes  6 to 8 working days.

Comment: Why leave, friend? There are [other options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337454/284349).

Comment: Fyi, it's not possible for the request to "fall through a crack" here. It's a queue that lists everyone waiting to be processed, not individual tickets being created or anything. So long as the message is still there, you're still in the queue. I'm not aware of the schedules of the people involved with processing that queue, though.

Comment: I am sorry that you are leaving. We all have different opinions, we all have different voices. Sometimes we agree, sometimes we don't. But our differences make us rich... every departure is a huge loss. Take care!

Comment: @Fermi paradoxI am leaving Meta SE because the issue with Monica is settled; there will be no further developments, IMO.  I feel very strongly that Monica was treated horribly, and am sickened by the whole Mess.  Many people have done their best to achieve a better resolution, and I am proud to have helped in even a small way.  I don't yet know what I will do about the small sites on which I have a long history and have some specialized expertise to contribute.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Sometimes there is no need to react to the provocative phrasing, but you just leave even when they frame it the wrong way. They make the rules, but you decide if you still want to play with them.

Comment: Why do you need to leave? Can't you just silently scale down activity (to 50%, 10%, 1%, 0.1%, or 0.00001%) or silently suspend all activity indefinitely? And perhaps come back later for one or the other reason? If it is for protest, it is probably more effective than rage quitting to leave something subtle (or not so subtle) on the user profile page, like a link to a blog post. Be [stoic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stoic#Adjective), man/women.

Comment: @ Peter Mortensen  Thanks for your concern! I'll probably stay on the three or four sites where I started years ago.  I became active on Meta only because of the Monica situation, and now that it is resolved, although highly unsatisfactorily from my point of view, I simply have no heart to stay.  It is not rage, it is sorrow.